# i3 bar replace tray icons by text

Tags: icons, i3

I would like to know how if it is possible to replace icons like the ones of nm-applet by text, and how I can do this if it's possible.

The main reason I wan't to do this is because I use i3-gaps next with bar transparency and icons doesn't have the same color as the bar and it looks really ugly.

Maybe I can map a script to popup nm-appklet's menu but I have never seen anything like that before and I have no clue how I can do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While you can't replace tray icons (unless you code your custom tray implementation) for network configuration you could use custom scripts to control connections and display their status and with them you should be able to replace basic functions of `nm-applet`:

- https://github.com/firecat53/networkmanager-dmenu
- https://github.com/march-linux/connman_dmenu

Comment: Could change the icons by choosing a different icon theme, though? If So, that it seems you could fork a theme and create your own "nm-applet" icon that has the desired colores to match the rest of the layout.